# what is function can sum two big numbers php

Tags: php, sum, numbers

I'm trying to Sum of two large numbers for some reason

```
<?php
$a = 50000000000.000000000000000000;
$b = 100000000000000000000000000000;
$sum = $a+$b;
echo $sum;
```

But the output appears like this:

> 1.0E+290

Is there a function that can be used to sum two large numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bcmath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension that provide [functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) to perform mathematical operations with numbers of any size and precision up to 2147483647 decimal digits, if there is sufficient memory.

Example :

```
<?php
$a = '50000000000.000000000000000000';
$b = '100000000000000000000000000000';
echo bcadd($a,$b);
// result : 100000000000000000050000000000
```